# How can I get a colored box around text on my HTML5/CSS3 website?

Tags: html, css, web

Text is a little difficult to read on my current [website](http://www.affinitibrokerage.com) -- I'd like to add a semi-transparent black box around my text area. Is there anyway to do this?

Here's a rough example of what I want to do:

[image: rough example of what I want]

Thanks!

Comment: just use on ur main div with text opacity:0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in a `div` container and give that div a `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);`. `0.7` being the opacity.

Comment: Excellent. Now, is there a way to make the darker background slightly wider/taller than the text box? Sorry for the noob questions here..

Comment: Use `padding: 5px;` on the container for example, see this [padding w3 page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).
Make sure to mark the question answered by hitting the check button on this answer.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured it out myself and came to answer/close it. Thanks again!